# Pandas SQLalchemy: complex filter on database columns

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am new to both SQLalchemy and pandas. I am writing a python code to query a mysql database.

I am fetching data from the database and keeping my data in a pandas dataframe. I could make simple operations on pandas dataframe columns like

Example1: get the rows where all columns have some values `[Col1 and Col2 and Col3]`.

Example2: get the rows where either of the columns have some values `[Col1 or Col2 or Col3]`.

Example3: `[Col1 or Col2]` and `[Col3 or Col4]`.

This is what I could achieve so far with pandas `dataframe[col_list].notnull().any(axis=1)` operation. Now I have to do some complex statments like `[[Col1 OR Col2] AND [Col3 OR Col4]] OR [Col5 OR Col6]`. These statments are provided by user as an input to the script.

I was wondering if there is a more convinent way to do this with (giving directly as a logic statment) or directly with sqlalchemy queries?

Thanks,

Rtut

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to filter your dataframe. For example, you can do things like

```
filtered = df[(df['Column 1'] == 'some value') or (df['Column 2'] == 'some value') and (df['Column 3'] > 15)]
```